# Carousel using syncfusion in Xamarin forms not appear

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to work with the syncfusion Carousel in xamarin
forms

however I have written this code per the dcoument and however for some reason
the Carosel is not appearing here is the code I have written

and here is the exmple:
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfcarousel/getting-started

Xaml:

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <syncCarousel:SfCarousel x:Name="carousel" BindingContext="{Binding CollectionOfItems}"  Offset="20" RotationAngle="45" DataSource="{Binding CollectionOfItems}"  HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="800" />

        <!--<c:CarouselViewControl x:Name="CaruselViewCon" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}">
            <c:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding LabelText}"   Aspect="Fill"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </c:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        </c:CarouselViewControl>-->
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    private ObservableCollection<SfCarouselItem> collectionOfItems;

    public ObservableCollection<SfCarouselItem> CollectionOfItems
    {
        get
        {
            return collectionOfItems;
        }

        set
        {
            collectionOfItems = value;
        }
    }


    public MainPage(Conferance conferance,string userPhone, List<EventDetails> LEventDEtails,List<CPhoto> LPhoto)
    {

        InitializeComponent();            
        collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ImageName = LPhoto[0].Path });
        collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ImageName = LPhoto[1].Path });
        collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ImageName = LPhoto[2].Path });

        carousel.ItemsSource = CollectionOfItems;
        carousel.BindingContext = CollectionOfItems;
 }
```

Comment: images should be there in resources or drawable folder in order to render images

Comment: I am taking them from a URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and I have modified it to display the image through URI:

```
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CollectionOfItems = new ObservableCollection<SfCarouselItem>();
    collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ItemContent = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/images/Images/Ubuntu_Server_Succinctly_img.png?v=04082017080611"))}});
    collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ItemContent = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/images/Images/Go_Web_Development.png?v=04082017080611")) } });
    collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ItemContent = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/images/downloads/ebooks/AutoCAD_Succinctly_coverimage.png?v=04082017080611")) } });
    collectionOfItems.Add(new SfCarouselItem() { ItemContent = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/images/Images/MongoDB_3_Succinctly_final.png?v=04082017080611")) } });

    carousel.ItemsSource = CollectionOfItems;
    carousel.BindingContext = CollectionOfItems;
}
```